# How to speed up compilation of multiple template type definition? (macOS, Clang)

Tags: c++, templates, clang

### Problem

I am porting a C++ library to macOS (with **Clang** compiler). It seems it stucks at some point and **delays compilation time up to 60+ min**. After isolating the problem I figured out it is caused by this monster template definition *(replaced class names)*:

```
auto table = std::make_shared<ClassE<ClassD<ClassC<ClassB<ClassA>>>>(loader);
```

All classes are templates and contains constructor *(except ClassA)* similar to this:

```
template<typename T> class ClassB: public T {
public:
    template<typename...ARGS> ClassB(ARGS&&...args):T(args...){}
    //...
};
```

When I remove that template line of code, it compiles normaly, in few seconds. It works fine with Windows (Visual Studio) and Linux platforms, so it is probably broken with macOS compiler (XCode, Apple's LLVM, Clang).

### Qustion

I would like to avoid fixing all the classes, is there a way, how to **rewrite** that definition to solve really slow compilation?

Comment: the compilation time is not necessarily in that line that you show here, but more likely in the code for the classes. If you dont use an instantiation of those templates they wont get compiled which would explain the extreme drop in compilation time. What you show here does not explain 60 minutes of compilation...

Comment: The templates B..E look trivial (unless there's a _lot_ of code or other dependencies you haven't shown: the constructor itself isn't complicated). What happens if you just `make_shared<ClassA>(loader)`? What about `make_shared<ClassB<ClassA>>(loader)`? You should be able to see where the slowdown occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If by removing that template line of code, your code still compiles then these template constructors may not be necessary (you should test to be sure). But since compilation time is increased when these constructors are presents that means the compiler requires the definitions of theses templates.

I suppose that these template constructors are called when present because they take precedence (or even disable implicit definition of default constructor) over special member functions: default constructor and copy/move constructor.

So if you don't want to touch these line of code, you could declare defaulted special constructors in such a way that they are always better match than these templates for copy and default construction, or may prefer to constrain the template constructors:

**Option 1**:

```
template<typename T> class ClassB: public T {
public:
    ClassB() =default;
    ClassB(const ClassB&) =default;
    ClassB(ClassB&&) =default;
    ClassB(ClassB&) =default; //also, to be a better match
    ClassB(const ClassB&&) =default; //idem

    template<typename...ARGS> ClassB(ARGS&&...args):T(args...){}
    //...don't have to worry any more if you declare another
    //...template constructor
};
```

**Option 2**:

```
template<typename T> class ClassB: public T {
public:

    template<typename Arg,typename...ARGS,
      class=std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Arg>,ClassB>>>
    ClassB(Arg&& arg,ARGS&&...args):T(arg,args...){}
    //... You should apply this constrain to all template
    //...  constructors that have a similar signature
};
```